# tmux dividers rendering improperly

Tags: tmux

So I (somehow) just started using `tmux` a couple days ago, and (needless to say) it's amazing. I have a nice little initialization script that pulls up all my rails/db/vim etc stuff and a lot of that was thanks to answers here. However, I'm still having a couple relatively minor problems, one of which I hope someone can help me with here. Basically, the dividers are rendering in a very strange manner. They have odd special characters in the middle (similar to �) and the lines wrap around to two lines when I switch to certain panes. I have attached a couple screenshots for reference. Any idea what might be going on?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuUUh.png (before the wraparound)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs0dE.png (after switching to the bottom-right pane)

Edit: I might should add I'm ssh-ing to my Ubuntu 13.10 from ChromeOS.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
fuser `tty`
```

to list all processes writing in the same virtual terminal ?

Comment: only one thing: `/dev/pts/23:         11134`

Comment: And what does it show on the other side of the ssh connection ? If you type `mesg`, what is shown ? `y` or `n` ?

Comment: It displays `is y`. You mean on the Ubuntu side, right? The machine I'm ssh-ing into? ChromeOS' shell doesn't have `mesg` apparently.

Comment: Then try if `mesg n` solves something. What is the current value of $TERM on both sides ?

Comment: `mesg n` returned nothing for me. `$TERM` is `xterm` on chromeos and I played around with it on ubuntu until I got it to `xterm-256color` (originally it was `screen-256color`).